# how or Unable to send mail via office 365 smtp

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller

I am trying to send mail via office365 smtp server but it prompts with "Failure sending mail."
Detailed report says "{"Unable to read data from the transport connection: net_io_connectionclosed."}"

here is my code

```
public string SendEmail(string To, string Sub, string Desc)
    {
       string mess = "";
        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
        mail.Subject = Sub;
        mail.From = new MailAddress(SenderEmail);
        mail.To.Add(To);
        mail.Body = Desc;
        mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("smtp-mail.outlook.com", 587);
        smtp.EnableSsl = true;
        smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        NetworkCredential netCre = new NetworkCredential(SenderEmail, SenderPass);
        smtp.Credentials = netCre;
        try
        {
            smtp.Send(mail);
            mess = "Success";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            mess = "Fail";
            return ex.Message;
        }
       return mess;
    }
```

Web.config will be

```
           <add key="Sendermail" value="email" />
           <add key="SenderPassword" value="password" />
```

Note : the email address is domain configured. When i try using gmail smtp port to send mail it works fine , only for outlook(office365) i am facing the issue

Answer (score 0):

Overall your solutions seems correct though there could be a couple for things causing it from TLS issues or host have you tried smtp.office365.com as the Server/Host?

A few other options to check/test could be found here :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/mail-flow-best-practices/how-to-set-up-a-multifunction-device-or-application-to-send-email-using-office-3

Comment: i did try still same issue ... do we have to add my domain name some were in the code coz my mail id will be like "xxxx@xxx.com.sg".

Comment: Should be something like  {mx-domain}.mail.protection.outlook.com  but you have to find it from Office365 configiuration MX record.